# Is it natural to say "tuck in the flaps of the medicine box to close it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Medicine or pills are often stored in boxes like the above picture.

Is the above box called "**a pill box**" or "**medicine box**"?

And to close the box, we have to fold its flaps in a certain way.

Is it natural to say "**tuck in the flaps of the medicine box to close it**"?

Comment: The box in the photo seems to have contained eye drops, so it is not a pill box! Most people would just say 'the box' (or carton) unless it's necessary to identify it as 'the box the eye drops came in'. Yes, they are called flaps, but, again, you can just say 'close the box/carton'.

Comment: You would only say "close the box by folding in the flaps" (or some such phrase) to a small child who hasn't yet closed that type of box. You don't need to explain every action to an adult. So no, it is unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

This is what many older people will think of as a pillbox. Note the shape.

[image]